# Select the last 48 hours dynamically

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with 2 dates.

```
Date A
Date B
```

I need to select all the rows where date B happened WITHIN 48 hours after date A.

Sample Data

```
Date A          Date B
1/28/2011   1/19/2014
12/21/2010  1/18/2014
2/5/2014    2/7/2014
```

In this case the 3rd row qualifies

Comment: What language? Platform?

Comment: Oops sorry.  Didn't see the tag.  Serves me right for skimming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DATEADD()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) should do the trick. `SELECT DATEADD(hh, 48, getdate())` returns 48 hours from now.

In your example you could replace `getdate()` with Date A, somewhere along the lines of:

```
SELECT DateB
FROM   x
WHERE  DateB BETWEEN DateA AND DATEADD(hh, 48, DateA)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DateA, DateB
FROM dbo.TableName
WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, DateA, DateB) <= 48
```

[Sql-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cb5eb/2/0)

Use `ABS` if it's not important which date is earlier.